# How to assign margin to child div to not float out of the parent div?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
       <!-- just blank div -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I applied CSS like this:

```
.parent {
   background: #eee;
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px; 
   border: 1px solid #000;
}

.child {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: red;
   margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Now you can see this in [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/392Ak/), it works as expected. But I want here that `.child` div automatically wrap inside the parent and not floating extra size out the parent.

One way to do this, is to set `width: auto` to child, but this works only if we have some text inside the `.child` div. Suppose I have blank `.child` div as in this case. So how can I do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `margin-left: 20px;` on the child element, use `padding-left: 20px;` on the parent element using `box-sizing: border-box;` property. This way, the `padding` of the parent element will be counted inside the element instead of outside which will make `420px` in `width`, hence by using `border-box` as a value, you can achieve this..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/392Ak/3/)

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
   background: #eee;
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
    padding-left: 20px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}

.child {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: red;
}
```

---

> Note: Using `*` will apply the properties on each and every element on
>   the page, if you are not willing to apply the `box-sizing:
>   border-box;` to all elements, consider applying that only on the
>   [parent element](http://jsfiddle.net/392Ak/4/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to the CSS of `.parent`

```
padding: 20px;
```

This will ensure that `.child` div will always be 20px away from the inner border of `.parent`
Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/392Ak/)